# Memory use with indexing and summing in numpy array

Tags: numpy

I am using list comprehension to index a numpy array and sum the values:

```
df[col]=np.array([A_numpy_array[b].sum() for b in B_numpy_array])
```

My `A_numpy_array` is indexed using the elements `b` of `B_numpy_array` (which has 8-9 million elements).

This part of the code is where the process takes awhile and I completely run out of RAM and begin to write to the disk.

To my knowledge, list comprehension is one of the most efficient methods in Python. Also, setting the pandas column this way is also efficient in pandas.

Is there and alternative way to slice `A_numpy_array` using the index values held in `b` that would allow me to get the sum of the values in a more memory efficient way?

Comment: Knowing the `shape `of `A_numpy_array` and `B_numpy_array` may help.  You could first run the list comprehension (or even just part of it), and then try to make the array from it.   Just from your description it is hard to know exactly where the memory use occurs.

Comment: The shapes would be something like (157561, 1) and (8000000,) respectively. Each b is an array of integers.

Comment: So `B_numpy_array` is `object` dtype with element arrays that vary in shape?  What kinds of shapes.  `A_numpy_array[b]` what sort of shape is this? But with `sum()`, that's reduced to a scalar, so the resulting array will be the same shape as `B_numpy_array` (but probably float dtype).  The `df` must also be quite large.  Does 'col' already exist, or are you adding a column to the frame?  You see, I'm just working through the problem in my head.  It would be nice if you'd actually done that for us.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data and how precise you want to be, changing the type of your data is the easiest way to reduce memory usage.

Check [Numpy's Data Types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) and [Pandas' Data Types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dtypes) for more information.

For example, sacrificing some calculations by using `float32` instead of `float64` can save you a lot of memory.

Before starting to dive in on how to optimize your code, it's worth trying this simple solution.

Comment: Which array do you propose changing?

Comment: both of course, but A seems more critical